# Java 8 using stream, flatMap and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I have this piece of code and I want to return a list of postCodes:

```
List<String> postcodes = new ArrayList<>();
List<Entry> entries = x.getEntry(); //getEntry() returns a list of Entry class
for (Entry entry : entries) {
    if (entry != null) {
       Properties properties = entry.getContent().getProperties();
       postcodes.addAll(Arrays.asList(properties.getPostcodes().split(",")));
   }
} 
return postcodes;
```

Here's my attempt to use stream() method and the following chained methods:

```
...some other block of code
List<Entry> entries = x.getEntry.stream()
    .filter(entry -> recordEntry != null)
    .flatMap(entry -> {
        Properties properties = recordEntry.getContent().getProperties();
        postCodes.addAll(Arrays.asList(properties.getPostcodes().split(",")));
});
```

Comment: first: filter(entry -> recordEntry != null) i guess this is wrong

Comment: second: why using streams for that?

Comment: third: whats the compilation error?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Missing return statement is the smallest of his problems :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you've got several issues with your code i.e:

1. `postCodes.addAll` is a *side-effect* and therefore you should avoid doing that otherwise when the code is executed in parallel you'll receive n*on-deterministic* results.
2. `flatMap` expects a stream, not a boolean; which is what your code currently attempts to pass to `flatMap`.
3. `flatMap` in this case consumes a function that also consumes a value and returns a value back and considering you've decide to use a lambda statement block then you must include a return statement within the lambda statement block specifying the value to return. this is not the case within your code.
4. stream pipelines are driven by *terminal* operations which are operations that turn a stream into a *non-stream* value and your code currently *will not execute at all* as you've just set up the ingredients but not actually *asked for a result* from the stream.
5. the receiver type of your query should be `List<String>` not `List<Entry>` as within your current code the call to `Arrays.asList(properties.getPostcodes().split(","))` returns a `List<String>` which you then add to an accumulator with the call `addAll`.
6. thanks to Holger for pointing it out, you're constantly failing to decide whether the variable is named `entry` or `recordEntry`.

That said here's how I'd rewrite your code:

```
List<String> entries = x.getEntry.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(Entry::getContent)
        .map(Content::getProperties)
        .map(Properties::getPostcodes‌)
        .flatMap(Pattern.co‌mpile(",")::splitAsS‌tream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and you may want to use `Collectors.toCollection` to specify a specific implementation of the list returned if deemed appropriate.

**edit:**

with a couple of good suggestions from shmosel we can actually use method references throughout the stream pipelines and therefore enabling better intent of the code and a lot easier to follow.

or you could proceed with the approach:

```
List<String> entries = x.getEntry.stream()
       .filter(e -> e != null)
       .flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(
         e.getContent().getProperties().getPostcodes().split(",")).stream()
       )
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if it's more comfortable to you.

Comment: You can replace `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` with `Arrays.stream(...)` or `Stream.of(...)`.

Comment: @shmosel true, very much appreciated for the suggestion.

Comment: If you prefer method references, you can also do `.map(Entry::getContent).map(Content::getProperties).map(Properties::getPostcodes).flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)`.

Comment: @shmosel once again very much appreciated. :)

Comment: You don’t need `Arrays.asList(…).stream()`; use `Arrays.stream(…)` to get a stream in the first place. And the list of issues is incomplete. Another issue of the original code is that the OP constantly fails to decide whether the variable is named `entry` or `recordEntry`.

Comment: @Holger I've intentionally left it as `Arrays.asList(…).stream()` to keep it consistent with OPs current approach, though as always you're correct and it would be better to use `Arrays.stream(…)`.  regarding your second point; I did see the issue with OP failing to decide on the variable name `entry` or `recordEntry`  but for some reason decided to not mention it (which I should have done).  very much appreciated once again.